# Floating Action Button size changed automatically

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

***Thanks to all. It's Solved***

But I didn't get the exact reason why did this happen. Because few hours ago it was in it's normal state and I didn't make any changes to code. Why did this thing happen?

***Problem***

My app's FAB size has been changed. I don't know why. I didn't change the FAB size. I tried all things like Rebuild project, clean project etc. First I was thinking its an Android studio's bug and searched on web. But couldn't find anything. Then, I reinstalled android studio but that didn't help me. Therefore, I am asking this question.

here is the xml code for Floating Action Button

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

[image: Older version of app]

This is an older version of app and I didn't change anything in this except icon. But that didn't effect it.

[image: Latest version]

This is the latest version of app. And both screen shots are taken from same mobile. Now compare `FloatingActionButton`s in both images. You will see a difference in size.

Not just this `FloatingActionButton`, all `FloatingActionButton`s of my app became smaller in size. Thanks in advance.

Comment: fab:fab_size="mini" or fab:fab_size="Normal "put this

Comment: Where to change i did't added that in my code

Comment: @HarishKamboj Are you talking about size of + icon inside fab or size of fab itself?

Comment: I am talking about fab's size not for icon. I also tried to provide the size to fab but that is also not working

Comment: Thanks guys, Problem is solved now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

need to add this line in this code : `app:fabSize="normal"`

Copy paste the below code and see :)

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
<!-- need to add this line in this code-->
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below property in XML: size can be mini, normal, large

```
app:fabSize="mini"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `app:fabSize="normal"` inside the FAB Xml.

Comment: Thanks problem solved, but did't get the exact reason because few hours ago it was in its normal state and I did't changed any thing in that code so why this thing happen ?

Answer (score 0):

For small size:

```
app:fab_size="mini"
```

For normal:

```
app:fab_size="Normal "
```